# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' on onClick

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface Alertprops {
    showAlert?: showAlertType,
    HideAlert?: () => void,
    onClick?: () => void,

}

interface Alertstate {
    alertMess?: string,
    showAlert?: boolean,
    alertType?: string,
    showReload?: boolean,
    

}

class Alert extends Component<Alertprops,Alertstate> {
    constructor(props:Alertprops) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            alertMess:'',
        }
    }

alertBox() {
        return (
            <div className="inner-box">
                {this.state.alertMess}
                <br/>
                {this.state.showReload ? (<a className="reload-link" onClick={()=>{window.location.reload()}}>Reload page</a>):(null)}
                <a onClick={()=>{this.props.HideAlert()}} className="close-alert">X</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

on **onClick={()=>{this.props.HideAlert()}}** I get error "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'" what Im doing wrong? just started use TS.

Comment: Can you show the `HideAlert()` function?

Comment: this is from redux export function HideAlert() {
    return {
      type: SHOW_ALERT,
      data: {ShowAlert:false}
    }
  }

Comment: You've defined the type as optional - `HideAlert?`. Typescript is helping you out by saying an error will be thrown if the optional prop is not provided (`undefined()`). You'll just need to check that the function is present before calling it, or require it in your interface. (`typeof this.props.HideAlert == 'function'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi if you pass function as props that can be undefined  you can pass it like this

```
this.props.HideAlert?.()
```

this can just run only if you get it as props